# Boost Audio Input on OS X?

Tags: macos, audio, audio-recording

I'm using my 13" Mac Book Pro's audio input functionality with an external microphone (recent vintage, bought around Thanksgiving).  I've increased my input volume to the maximum in system preference, but the resulting recorded volume (using iShowU HD) is very low.

Is there anyway to increase the input volume/sensitivity beyond Apple's default settings?  I've found plenty on google about increasing the OUTPUT volume, but I want to increase the input volume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a preamplifier, since the audio input expects `line level` and you are probably just using a microphone with no preamp. Either that or get a USB mic.